# How to add an attribute to a serialized XML node?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, xml-serialization

Assume I have a C# class like this:

```
[XmlRoot("floors")]
public class FloorCollection
{
    [XmlElement("floor")]
    public Floor[] Floors { get; set; }

}
```

And I want to serialize it and send to a REST API using WCF. But before sending I need adding an attribute to the floors node in this way: `<floors type="array">...</floors>`

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the type attribute into your collection class:

```
[XmlRoot("floors")]
public class FloorCollection
{
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("floor")]
    public Floor[] Floors { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mean adding that without the business code knowing about it, then you'll probably have to use [Message Inspectors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx) to modify the message before it is sent.